# Source for Chuppa Poem

Tags: sources-mekorot, song-poetry, wedding

What are the earliest sources for the מי בן שיח שושן חוחים  poem commonly recited at chuppot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is unknown but it appears in a Seder Birchat Hamazon printed in Venice in 1663 (see Edut L'Yisrael p. 62 and in the addenda in the back; see also [Shulchan HaEzer 2:7:4:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8556&st=&pgnum=67); http://www.bhol.co.il/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=2504783&forum_id=771). It is based on [Shir HaShirim Rabbah Parasha 2 : Perek 2](http://www.sefaria.org/Shir_HaShirim_Rabbah.2.2.4?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) about the verse "כשושנה בין החוחים" - "Like a bloom amongst the thorns"

> ר' חנן דצפורי פתר קרייה בגמילות חסדים ...ועוד בנוהג שבעולם עשרה בני
>   אדם נכנסין לבית המשתה ואין אחד מהן יכול לפתוח פיו לברך ברכת חתנים
>   ובא אחד ופתח פיו וברך ברכת חתנים. למה הוא דומה ביניהם? כשושנה בין
>   החוחים.
>
> Rabbi Hanan of Zippori interpreted the verse as referring to acts of kindness ...and also with the practice of the world, 10 men enter to the wedding hall and none can open their mouth to bless the wedding blessing and one came and opened his mouth and blessed the wedding blessing. To what is he compared amongst them? Like a bloom amongst thorns...

See also: http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/111826